# Git Pull Request-like process in Team Foundation Version Control

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

Suppose I have a team project with two branches: "main" and "dev" (fictional names).

As things are now, new code is merged into "main" without any code review. Also, anyone can check-in directly to it. We would like to change that.

I would really like to have something like Git's pull request functionality. I know we can use permissions to keep everyone from making check-ins at the main branch. We can also use permissions to make sure that only a reviewer can merge into the main branch.

But how can we review the difference between both branches before doing a merge?

I found out that the Code Review feature of TFS 2013 only works if you have the Premium edition of Visual Studio. Not all of the devs here have it, and we cannot install other editions for them, nor get VS2015 or later versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom check in policy for code review before checking in. There is an existing Code Review Checkin Policy can be downloaded from website below, this policy allows you to enforce Code Reviews at checkin time.:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for those who have the Premium Edition of Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: If so, you may need to use permissions as an alternative.